# Get entity in different json structure

Tags: sql, database, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot and i have an entity class like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "form_component")
public class FormComponent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String colSize;
    private Integer colNumber;
    private Integer rowNumber;
    private String colAlign;
}
```

and on an endpoint i'd like to receive all components grouped by row number. Like so:

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "components": [
                {"rowNumber": 0, "colNumber": 0, ...},
                {"rowNumber": 0, "colNumber": 1, ...}
            ]
        },
        {
            "components": [
                {"rowNumber": 1, "colNumber": 0, ...},
                {"rowNumber": 1, "colNumber": 1, ...}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Same goes for reverse, taking above json and saving components.

How can i achieve that, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might do something like this:

1. Define a query method in the `FormComponentRepository` that gives me all components.

   List components = formComponentRepository.findAll();
2. Then you need to group the list by `rowNumber`:

   Map< Integer, List> groups =  components.stream().collect(groupingBy(FormComponent::getRowNumber));
3. You can create a class that matches the JSON structure or just use a Map, then you can populate it iterating over the `groups` Map

The reverse process is simple, iterate over the JSON structure and make batch inserts or maybe just inserts for each component.